# after upgrade, Firefox 60 does not show checkbox on website

Tags: firefox, browser, chromium, firefox-quantum

I have upgraded Firefox to `Firefox Quantum 60.7.0-esr`.

The new Firefox version does not show checkbox on a particular website:

[image]

for comparison, here is a correctly displayed website in Chromium:

[image]

The old version of Firefox displayed the same webpage correctly.

**How can I fix this problem ?**

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to solve it:

1. Write to customer support, telling them about this bug and waiting for a new release;
2. Downgrade to the last working version and wait for a new release.

Other than that, there is little you can do about it.